# NLTK word_tokenize on French text is not woking properly

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, french

I'm trying to use NLTK `word_tokenize` on a text in **French** by using :

```
txt = ["Le télétravail n'aura pas d'effet sur ma vie"]
print(word_tokenize(txt,language='french'))
```

it should print:

```
['Le', 'télétravail', 'n'','aura', 'pas', 'd'','effet', 'sur', 'ma', 'vie','.']
```

But I get:

```
['Le', 'télétravail', "n'aura", 'pas', "d'effet", 'sur', 'ma', 'vie','.']
```

Does anyone know why it's not spliting tokens properly in French and how to overcome this (and other potential issues) when doing NLP in French?

Comment: Good question!!!

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the source of `word_tokenize` reveals, that the `language` argument is only used to determine how to split the input into sentences.
And for tokenization on word level, a (slightly modified) `TreebankWordTokenizer` is used which will work best for *english* input and contractions like *don't*.
From `nltk/tokenize/__init__.py`:

```
_treebank_word_tokenizer = TreebankWordTokenizer()
# ... some modifications done
def word_tokenize(text, language='english', preserve_line=False):
    # ...
    sentences = [text] if preserve_line else sent_tokenize(text, language)
    return [token for sent in sentences
            for token in _treebank_word_tokenizer.tokenize(sent)]
```

To get your desired output, you might want to consider using a different tokenizer like a `RegexpTokenizer` as following:

```
txt = "Le télétravail n'aura pas d'effet sur ma vie"
pattern = r"[dnl]['´`]|\w+|\$[\d\.]+|\S+"
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(pattern)
tokenizer.tokenize(txt)
# ['Le', 'télétravail', "n'", 'aura', 'pas', "d'", 'effet', 'sur', 'ma', 'vie']
```

My knowledge of French is limited and this only solves the stated problem. For other cases you will have to adapt the pattern.
You can also look at the implementation of the `TreebankWordTokenizer` for ideas of a more complex solution.
Also keep in mind that this way you will need to split sentences beforehand, if necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and explanations! appreciated!

Comment: I tried and I don't get your solution. With the pattern you wrote, I get the following : 

['Le', 'télétravail', 'n', '’aura', 'pas', 'd', '’effet', 'sur', 'ma', 'charge', 'de', 'travail', '.']  The apostrophy is attached to the second word instead of the first (for "n'aura" and  "d'effet").

Comment: I'm using nltk version 3.2.5. Did you copy the pattern from my posted snippet? The order of the groups in the regex is actually important, the `[dnl]'` should be the first part of the pattern. What I wrote is only a quick example and surely can be improved.

Comment: Hello, yes I copied/pasted your pattern. will try to learn more about patterns handeling in Python (am not very good at it). I'm using the most updated version of nltk. Thanks again a lot for showing me the way.

Comment: Are you using python2? I did this in python3 and this has an impact on how strings are treated. I also edited the snippet in my answer to account for different kinds of apostrophes. Probably the easiest solution is to go with the `MosesTokenizer` suggested by alvas. I wasn't aware of its implementation in nltk.

Comment: Thanks VaID, it worked nicely now (using Python3) :-) Probably indeed a question of the different types of apostrophes. Will have a look at MosesTokenizer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an explicit French model for `word_tokenize` (which is the modified treebank tokenizer used for the English Penn Treebank). '

The `word_tokenize` function performs sentence tokenization using the `sent_tokenize` function before the actual word tokenization. The `language` argument in `word_tokenize` is only used for the `sent_tokenize` part.

Alternatively, you can use the `MosesTokenizer` that has some language dependent regexes (and it does support French):

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize.moses import MosesTokenizer
>>> moses = MosesTokenizer(lang='fr')
>>> sent = u"Le télétravail n'aura pas d'effet sur ma vie"
>>> moses.tokenize(sent)
[u'Le', u't\xe9l\xe9travail', u'n&apos;', u'aura', u'pas', u'd&apos;', u'effet', u'sur', u'ma', u'vie']
```

If you want don't like it that Moses escape special XML characters, you can do:

```
>>> moses.tokenize(sent, escape=False)
[u'Le', u't\xe9l\xe9travail', u"n'", u'aura', u'pas', u"d'", u'effet', u'sur', u'ma', u'vie']
```

---

To explain why splitting `n'` and `d'` is useful in French NLP.

Linguistically, separating the `n'` and `d'` does make sense because they're clitiques that have their own syntactic and semantic properties but bounded to the root/host.

In French, `ne ... pas` would have been a discontinuous constituent to denote negation, the clitique nature of `ne` going to `n'` is because of the vowel onset in the word following `ne`, so splitting the `n'` from the `aura` does make it easier to identify `ne ... pas`.

In the case of `d'`, it's the same phonetic motivation of the vowel onset in the following word to go from `de effet` -> `d'effet`.

Comment: yes, thank you for your reply. linguistically "n' ....pas"  equals "ne pas" in French (discontinuous constituent). In the case of  " d' " of "d'effet",  "d'" should be considered as a stopword (as it does not bring any interesting info about the meaning of the sentence). However after checking it using print (stopwords.words('french')), I realized "d'" is not tagged as a stop word in nltk.corpus. ( "de" is) . That's a problem. Do you know by any chance how I could add stopwords to the current stopwords list in French in nltk.corpus?

Comment: Yes, adding the clitique form should be possible. Please create an issue https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data as a feature request.

Comment: Do you know by anychance if  (n'.....pas) is considered as a negation group in the current implementation? (equivalent to "ne....pas").

Comment: No it isn't. Discontinuous constituents are infamously hard to catch.

Comment: ok, I realized after further investigation that "d" is a stopword in nltk.copus  (french) but "d' " is not. That is odd... I would have expected to have "d'" with apostrophy as a stopword and not just the letter "d"... Does that mean that I should tokenize my sentence this way : ['Le', 'télétravail', 'n','aura', 'pas', 'd','effet', 'sur', 'ma', 'vie', ' `', '.' ] with the apotrophy seperately ?

Comment: MosesTokenizer does the work. The only issue is escape = false does not seem to escape special XML characters (I opened an issue about it on github) I get the same result on  moses.tokenize(sent, escape=False) an  moses.tokenize(sent, escape=True ) ==> ['Le', 'télétravail', 'n&apos;', 'aura', 'pas', 'd&apos;', 'effet', 'sur', 'ma', 'vie']  (Python 3) - Do you have an idea why the escape flag is not working ?

Comment: According to https://www.nltk.org/news.html?highlight=moses , Moses tokenizer has been removed...

Answer (score 0):

Here we see that the processing of the French elision is not satisfactory. So, I recommend correcting the problem with post-processing of elision from the NLTK `word_tokenize` output.

```
compiled_pattern = re.compile(r"([a-zA-ZÀ-Ÿ]+['’])([a-zA-ZÀ-Ÿ]*)")

def split_in_words_fr(text):
    tokens = word_tokenize(text)
    new_tokens = []
    for token in tokens:
        search_results = re.findall(r"['’]",token)
        if search_results and len(search_results) == 1:
            new_tokens.extend(re.split(compiled_pattern,token)[1:3])
        else:
            new_tokens.append(token)
    return new_tokens
```

Then:

```
print(split_in_words_fr("Le télétravail n'aura pas d'effet sur ma vie"))
```

gives:

```
['Le', 'télétravail', "n'", 'aura', 'pas', "d'", 'effet', 'sur', 'ma', 'vie']
```

---

A less satisfactory solution is to use wordpunct_tokenize which splits on every non alphanum characters.

```
from nltk.tokenize import wordpunct_tokenize

print(wordpunct_tokenize("Le télétravail n'aura pas d'effet sur ma vie"))
```

which gives

```
['Le', 'télétravail', 'n', "'", 'aura', 'pas', 'd', "'", 'effet', 'sur', 'ma', 'vie']
```