# Word tokenizer not picking up " this's "

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Having an issue with understanding why NLTK's word_tokenizer looks at the string "this's" and splits it into "this" "'" "s" instead of keeping them together. I've tested with "test's" and this works fine. When I tested with "results'" it split the apostrophe again. Is this just a particular thing that will happen with apostrophes?

Comment: I think this's (heh!) relevant: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/145503

Comment: Have you tried adding \ before.  IE `'this\'s'`?

Comment: @Simon , I tried and didn't work

Comment: All good, just parsed it myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a normal behavior of NLTK and tokenizers in general to split `this's` -> `this` + `'s`. Because `'s` a clitique and they are two separate syntactic units.

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> word_tokenize("this's")
['this', "'s"]
```

For the case of result it's the same:

```
>>> word_tokenize("results'")
['results', "'"]
```

## Why are the `'s` and `'` a separate entity from its host?

For the case of `this's`, `'s` is an abbreviated form of `is` which denotes copula. In some cases, it's ambiguous and it can also denote possessive.

And for the 2nd case of `results'`, `'` is denoting possessive.

So if we POS tag the tokenized forms we get:

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
>>> pos_tag(word_tokenize("results'"))
[('results', 'NNS'), ("'", 'POS')]
```

For the case of `this's`, the POS tagger thinks it's a possessive because people seldom use `this's` in written text:

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
>>> pos_tag(word_tokenize("this's"))
[('this', 'DT'), ("'s", 'POS')]
```

But if we look at `He's` -> `He` + `'s`, it's clearer that `'s` is denoting the copula:

```
>>> pos_tag(word_tokenize("He's good."))
[('He', 'PRP'), ("'s", 'VBZ'), ('good', 'JJ'), ('.', '.')]
```

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47384013/610569